# How should I use Primefaces Dock component?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to use dock menu, but it doesn't work. (it shows the images but it doesn`t zoom on them when I move the mouse over it). I want to use it in the center layout-unit of my page, inserting another page which acctualy contains the dock. The code looks like this:

template.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body.ui-layout-container { background-color: cadetblue;}
    </style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:layout fullPage="true" resizeTitle="resize">
        <p:layoutUnit position="north" id="north" resizable="false" size ="75">
            <ui:include src="header.xhtml" />
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="west" id="west" resizable="false" style="height:580px;overflow:hidden;" size="180">
            <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <**p:layoutUnit styleClass="layoutUnitCenter" position="center">
                 !!Here I insert the page which contains the dock
                <ui:insert name="content" />
        </p:layoutUnit>**

        <p:layoutUnit position="south" resizable="true" id="south" size="40">
            <ui:include src="footer.xhtml" />
        </p:layoutUnit>

    </p:layout>
</h:body>
</html>
```

dock.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    template="template.xhtml">   

 <ui:define name="content">
    <h:head>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
         <h:form>
           <p:dock position="top">  
                   <p:menuitem value="teachers" icon="/images/dock/teacher.png" url="#"/>  
                   <p:menuitem value="students" icon="/images/dock/student.png" url="#"/>  
                   <p:menuitem value="parents" icon="/images/dock/parent.png" url="#"/>  
           </p:dock> 
       </h:form>
    </h:body>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

I tried to use the dock.xhtml by itself, without the ui:composition and it works just fine. But when I try to use it like this, it only shows the images, but doesn`t do anything when I move the mouse over the images. Another problem is that it doesn`t put the dock in the center of the area. It positions it a little to the left. 
I`m pretty new to jsf and Primefaces, so any answer might help.

Answer (score 0):

This code generate the same issue you asked help for:

[image: issued code]

This little change, solved for me:

[image]